# как передать переменную в модальное окно

Tags: php

Привет всем!
подскажите пожалуйста где моя ошибка?
Смысл кода. Есть баннеры при клике выводиться модальное окно CSS . как мне передать в модальное окно переменную `i` если быть точным то она передается но только под номером один. В чём моя проблема?

```
$i = 0;
$s=10;
do
{
$i = $i +1;
      printf("  
      <a href='game.php#openModal' ><img src='img/lanshaft/Capture.PNG' title='%s'/></a>
      <div id='openModal' class='modalDialog'>
      <div>
      <a href='#close' title='Закрыть' class='close'>X</a>
        <h2> номер %s</h2>
        </div>
        </div>
      ",$i,$i);
if($i>=$s)
{
    printf("<br>");
    $s=$s+10;
}
}
while ($i <= =999);
```

Answer (score 2):

Ваша проблема в повторяющихся значениях атрибута `id='openModal'`.

> она передается но только под номером один

Потому что по селектору `"#openModal"` всегда находится первое окно.

```
printf("  
  <a href='game.php#openModal%s'>
    <img src='img/lanshaft/Capture.PNG' title='%s'/>
  </a>
  <div id='openModal%s' class='modalDialog'>
    <div>
      <a href='#close' title='Закрыть' class='close'>X</a>
      <h2> номер %s</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
",$i,$i,$i,$i);
```